# Windows 8 not available in GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I tried to install Ubuntu next to windows 8 (because I really don't like windows 8) but ubuntu lacks some of the things I need that I had on windows 8 for a class I am taking right now. Ubuntu is working, but the GRUB menu that comes up only shows Ubuntu as an option. Also, when I change my boot mode from legacy back to UEFI my computer either says operation system not found or Windows encountered a problem and needs to restart. I can't reinstall windows because I don't have my product key. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: go on the terminal and type `sudo update-grub` that should refresh the operating systems list and windows should pop on. If you have an issue still, download, install, and run boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. This should definitely fix your boot problems by reinstalling the windows bootloader

Comment: Updating the existing BIOS-mode GRUB will not help to boot the EFI-mode Windows installation. It's best to get both OSes booting in EFI mode, which requires installing an EFI-mode boot loader or boot manager.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a mixed-mode installation -- Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and Windows in EFI/UEFI mode. This is an awkward situation at best, and resulted from your following poor instructions (or perhaps running into a problem when following good instructions and improvising). The solution is to install an EFI boot loader for Linux. There are several ways to do this, but the two easiest are likely to be:

- If you haven't already done so, disable Secure Boot on your computer. (You can re-enable it later, if you like.) Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and prepare a medium with it. You should then be able to boot to rEFInd. If rEFInd enables you to boot both Windows and Ubuntu, you can then install the Debian-package version of rEFInd on your computer, which should take over the boot process and enable you to boot either OS directly.
- Boot an Ubuntu emergency disk *in EFI mode* and run the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) program. This should set up GRUB in EFI mode, which in turn should enable booting both Ubuntu and Linux. Note that this option is more of a "leap of faith" than the first, since it involves modifying your on-disk and in-NVRAM settings without first checking that anything will work. It can also be tricky to boot an Ubuntu emergency disk in EFI mode if you don't know your way around your particular firmware's settings.

Comment: Assuming Win8 gets up and runs, also remember to find and disable the fast-start options.

Comment: [This page](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) summarizes how to disable Fast Startup. Note that the options in question are *Windows* options, not firmware options. (Disabling an option with a similar name in the firmware is sometimes necessary, too; but if so, the firmware option will prevent booting from the USB drive, so if you can boot from that drive, don't bother. The Windows option can cause filesystem corruption and other weird errors.)